# does the constant in calculating time complexity have to be a integer number?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

suppose f(n) = O(g(n)) then we say that
0 <= f(n) <= cg(n) .

my question is does this 'c' have to be a integer . not only for big-O notation but for all other notations like omega and theta notation?

i want to solve the question n! = w(2^n) based upon that since the expression
comes out to be n! = c1*2^n. now i have to calculate c1 and n0>=n for that.

Comment: It does not have to be an integer, but since you can always round up to the next biggest integer, you can always choose an integer that works.

Comment: A good place to start looking for answers like this is to look at the definition of the thing you're asking about. For example the definition of wikipedia says "if there exists a positive real number..."

Comment: The comment by @btilly is correct for big O, but not true for big Omega (depending on just how you define it). x/2 = Omega(x), but there's no positive integer c such that x/2 >= cx for all large x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO , it does not have a integer . it can be any positive real number  and it also be in fraction also.